# How do I comment out the following block of code?

Tags: awk, sed

What I have:

```
...
    {if $dockerPipelinesEnabled}
        {call aui.buttons.button}
            {param text: getText('deployment.environment.docker.button') /}
            {param tagName: 'a' /}
            {param id: 'configureEnvironmentDocker' + $id /}
            {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentDocker.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {/call}
    {/if}

    {call aui.buttons.button}
        {param text: getText('deployment.project.environment.agents') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureEnvironmentAgents' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentAgents.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
    {/call}

    {call widget.override.aui.badgeButton}
        {param text: getText('environment.notifications') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureDeploymentsNotifications' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentNotifications.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {param badgeText: $notificationsNumberString /}
    {/call}
...
```

What I want:

```
...
    {if $dockerPipelinesEnabled}
        {call aui.buttons.button}
            {param text: getText('deployment.environment.docker.button') /}
            {param tagName: 'a' /}
            {param id: 'configureEnvironmentDocker' + $id /}
            {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentDocker.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {/call}
    {/if}

  /**  {call aui.buttons.button}
        {param text: getText('deployment.project.environment.agents') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureEnvironmentAgents' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentAgents.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
    {/call} */

    {call widget.override.aui.badgeButton}
        {param text: getText('environment.notifications') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureDeploymentsNotifications' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentNotifications.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {param badgeText: $notificationsNumberString /}
    {/call}
...
```

I can comment the unique lines in multiple statements however there are common lines in that block of code that are present in other blocks.

The acceptable formats are:

```
/**  {call aui.buttons.button}
        {param text: getText('deployment.project.environment.agents') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureEnvironmentAgents' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentAgents.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
    {/call} */
```

or:

```
 /**  {call aui.buttons.button} */
 /**    {param text: getText('deployment.project.environment.agents') /} */
 /**       {param tagName: 'a' /} */
 /**       {param id: 'configureEnvironmentAgents' + $id /} */
 /**       {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentAgents.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
 /**   {/call} */
```

**Edit**

<s>I was attempting to solve the problem with `sed` and `awk` but it looks to be fairly trivial with `grep`</s>:

```
grep --invert-match "$(grep -B 1 -A 4 .*deployment.project.environment.agents <path-to-file>
```

It looks like `grep` doesn't treat the match as a block but rather each line is removed which breaks the result.

**Update**

The full file is [here](https://zerobin.net/?5d96bbadc6ba7867#85lCkxRlMghERnkKM1ARcsfsVdpLYdBDUe76WqBnIqM=) (the snippet of interest is located towards the bottom)

In that file I wish to comment out the section above (shown in *acceptable formats*).

Note that `{call aui.buttons.button}` appears in multiple places so that alone is not enough of a marker. It would be acceptable to delete the block of code as well.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: lol nope. I have tried different permutations with `sed` and `awk` with no luck (I have very little exposure to the advanced capabilities). The bit I'm having trouble with is the match this line but comment the line before/after.

Comment: Is this something you have to repeat? Seems faster to manually edit the file than to come up with a script.

Comment: Yes, it will have to be repeated. It is something we need to do via our `Dockerfile` before building the image.

Comment: What distinguishes this particular block from any other similar block in the (elided) code? Can you say: from `{call aui.buttons.button}` through the `{/call}`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, as those two pieces of code appear elsewhere.

Comment: @kaizenCoder In the full file you posted, `{code...}...{/code}` blocks are nested inside each other, which means that any silly hack (like my awk script) would have to turn into a proper parser with tokenizer and stack if it were to have any chance to properly handle such kind of data other than by fluke ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, I get ya. Appreciate the effort you put into attempting to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sed`:

```
sed '/{call/ {:L; N; /{\/call/!bL; /deployment.project/ {s/^/\/**/; s/$/*\//}} ' file
    {if $dockerPipelinesEnabled}
        {call aui.buttons.button}
            {param text: getText('deployment.environment.docker.button') /}
            {param tagName: 'a' /}
            {param id: 'configureEnvironmentDocker' + $id /}
            {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentDocker.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {/call}
    {/if}

/**    {call aui.buttons.button}
        {param text: getText('deployment.project.environment.agents') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureEnvironmentAgents' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentAgents.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
    {/call}*/

    {call widget.override.aui.badgeButton}
        {param text: getText('environment.notifications') /}
        {param tagName: 'a' /}
        {param id: 'configureDeploymentsNotifications' + $id /}
        {param extraAttributes: [ 'href': contextPath() + '/deploy/config/configureEnvironmentNotifications.action?environmentId=' + $id ] /}
        {param badgeText: $notificationsNumberString /}
    {/call}
```

On each encountered `{call}` it collects lines into pattern space until `{/call}` found (see mosvy's caveat, though). Then, if the target pattern
is in the pattern space, add `/**` at the begin and `*/` at end of line.

Comment: Unfortunately, this comments every block that has a `{call` in it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See appended result in my answer.

Comment: I think you might be right. I tested this on the entire file (linked above) and what I missed was to extend the `/deployment.project/` to `/deployment.project.environment.agents/` to make it more granular. Let me test it further and get back to ya.

Comment: If you don't mind demystifying the `sed` command a little bit that'd be much appreciated!

Comment: see edited answwer.